# How do I display all the title above a pin in map view?

Tags: swift, dictionary, view, mkmapview

I have completed a map view application in Swift which adds pin to the map view. How do I automatically display all the title above the pin without clicking them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t think it´s possible to show all the titles for your annotations at the same time. There is only support to show one title at a time.

You can do that by adding this row:

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(mapView.annotations[0], animated: true)
```

Here I select the annotation with index `0`.